# method to create random colors according to some sets

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, random, background-color

In my javascript file, i have a set of couples eache constituted by a letter and a number, for exemple :  `{(A,5), (B,7), ..., (Z,3)}`.

For every couple `(A,x)` I have x divs in my html with a `style = "background-color: {{object.color}}"`.

I'd like to write a method that randomly computes x colors for each couple (A,x) such that :

- each color is enough different from the others to distinguish all of them.
- every colors of a same couple are enough close to identify this couple.

For exemple : I have this couples : `{(A,5), (B,4), (C,10)}` so I have 19 divs in my html. For all 5 divs of set A I compute a color of blue tint, for all 4 divs of set B I compute a color of green tint, and for all 10 divs of set C I compute a color of red tint.

Of course you don't know the couples by advance :)

Is there a way to do that maybe using the RGB value of each color on css or something like this ?

for the moment I have only made a method where I pick each color completly randomly only avoiding colors that are too much dark or too much white and with a loop to garantee a color already taken can't be taken twice :

```
   function(){
        var cb=0;
        var cr=0;
        var cg=0;
        var minEcart=40;
        var testB=true;
        var cptI=0;
        while(testB){
            testB=false;
            cr=Math.round(Math.random()*170) + 85;
            cb=Math.round(Math.random()*170) + 85;
            cg=Math.round(Math.random()*170) + 85;
            for(var j=0; j<$scope.colorAlreadyGiven.length;j++){
                if(($scope.colorAlreadyGiven[j][0]-cb>=-minEcart)&&
                    ($scope.colorAlreadyGiven[j][0]-cb<=minEcart)&&
                    ($scope.colorAlreadyGiven[j][1]-cg>=-minEcart)&&
                    ($scope.colorAlreadyGiven[j][1]-cg<=minEcart)&&
                    ($scope.colorAlreadyGiven[j][2]-cr>=-minEcart)&&
                    ($scope.colorAlreadyGiven[j][2]-cr<=minEcart)){
                        testB=true;
                        cptI++;
                        if(cptI>=50){
                            testB=false;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        $scope.colorAlreadyGiven.push([cb,cg,cr]);
        return "#"+(cb+cg*256+cr*65536).toString(16);
  }
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: for the moment I have a method that pick random colors avoiding ones that are too much dark or too much white and with a loop to be sure that any color already picked can't be picked a second time, but I have found nothing that can keep colors on a specific range allowing to know from which set I am.

Comment: @LyxtheLyxos - Hint: dont work in the RGBA colour-space. Work in the HSLA one. That way, only one of the components is responsible for the Hue or colour, another for the Saturation or amount of the colour, a third for the Luminance or brightness/darkness and a last for the Alpha value, which will likely be 100% (totally opaque) for your use case. Here's a HSLA colour-picker example: http://standardista.com/webkit/ch7/hsla.html Notice how much more human-friendly it is than RGBA? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article on lightening and darkening color with javascript https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lighten-darken-color/

You can pick a base shade, and then lighten or darken it to a random degree

Another method would be to generate a color palette using a CSS pre-processor (SASS or LESS) first, and then use javascript to randomly assign one of those pre-generated colors via either classnames or an attribute ( `.red1 .red2 .red3` or `[data-red-shade=1] [data-red-shade=2] [data-red-shade=3]` )

Comment: I'm not sure I can use one or the other proposition, because  in the first one I'm not sure the lighter tint is enought different to tell they are not the same just by one look, and for pre compute the colors I don't know by advance the number I need so it could be too much difficult to precompute every thing.
In addition if there are few colors to compute I may use big range of difference, on the other way if there is a lot of colors to compute I accepte colors that are quite close. So I'd prefere a method that take all that in account

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using lab colour space for that, since the calculations will be easier. Find colour conversion functions here: [Colour conversion in javascript](https://github.com/Qix-/color-convert).

The most basic Lab logic would look something like this:

1. Count the number of pairs into x;
2. Split A and B colour space into x sections (you can treat it as a 2D graph);
3. Use midpoint of each section for each pair;
4. For each pair, find the number of points equidistant on L scale.

Now you have for each pair a set of coordinates `{((a1,b1),[L1, L2, L3...]),((a1,b1),[L1, L2, L3...]), ((a1,b1),[L1, L2, L3...]), ...}`

As you go on, you will find better ways to arrange these.